# Matrix multiplication: error: too many arguments for method *:*

Tags: scala-breeze

```
scala> val B = DenseMatrix((0.5,0.2,0.3),
                        (0.1,0.4,0.5),
                        (0.25,0.35,0.4),
                        (0.6,0.2,0.2),
                        (0.7,0.1,0.2))


scala> (B *:* B)(::,1)
<console>:38: error: too many arguments for method *:*: (implicit op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpMulScalar.Impl2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],That])That
       (B *:* B)(::,1)
```

However if I tweak the code a little bit with double transpose, it works. What caused the error and is there any other way to work around it.

```
scala> (B *:* B).t.t(::,1)
res317: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.25, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0625, 0.36, 0.48999999999999994)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how implicits work in Scala.

```
 (B *:* B)(::,1)
```

expands as:

```
 B.*:*(B)(::,1)
```

but `*:*` is defined as (simplifying a bit):

```
def *:*[U, R](u: U)(implicit op: OpMulScalar.Impl2[T, U, R])
```

so Scala thinks you're trying to pass `(::, 1)` as an implicit argument. It's pretty annoying, admittedly.

To fix it, you can use your solution, or

```
 (B *:* B).apply(::,1)
```

or extract `(B *:* B)` as a val.